# My dropdown is not getting value on edit mode in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dropdown

I have dropdownlist which i am binding from Db but on edit view i check my cotroller it is getting the values of grade but y dropdown does not show the selecte grade instead it just populate the dropdown without selecting the one from the db.

I have make the model object as array[0] because i am creating dropdown list at run time i mean it is dynamic

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.educations[0].Grade, new SelectList(ViewBag.Grades, "Id", "Name"),  new { @id = "ddlGrades", @class = "btn form-text" })
```

That is what i have tried 
if i use `@html.textboxFor` then it get the 6 value from the db and bind the textbox to it but not working with dropdown

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.educations[0].Grade, new SelectList(ViewBag.Grades, "Id", "Name"),  new { @id = "ddlGrades", @class = "btn form-text" })

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.educations[0].Grade, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to pass your selected value to `SelectList` for edit view.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.educations[0].Grade, new SelectList(ViewBag.Grades, "Id", "Name",SelectedValue),  new { @id = "ddlGrades", @class = "btn form-text" })
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a limitation of the DropDownListFor helper which is not able to extract the value from a complex lambda expression such as the one you are using (a lambda expression containing array index access). One possible workaround is the following:

````
    person => person.Addresses[i].State, 
    new SelectList(
        Model.AvailableStates, 
        "Text", 
        "Value", 
        Model.Addresses[i].State
    )
) %>```
````